# #ASK Laravel Deep Eloquent Relationship, from Patient one-to-many Registration one-to-one Polyclinic

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

if I have a relation model like this: Patient Model one-to-many Registration Model, and Registration Model one-to-one Polyclinic Model. Is it possible to retrieve data from Patient Model directly to Polyclinic Model via the Registration Model with the eloquent relationship?

[image: Model Relationship between Patient one-to-many Registration one-to-one Polyclinic]

Because I have patient history page, through the registration model I want to retrieve the polyclinic name with the foreign key polyclinic_id in the Registration model.

[image: Patient History Page]

Numbers 2 and 3 that are highlighted are ID polyclinic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `with()` then send your data.

For example:

```
$patients->with('registrations.polyclinic');
```

But you need to define `registrations` relationship in your `Patient` model and `polyclinic` relationship in your `Registration` model. That way, you can get `Patient` object which has `registrations` key which contains of an array of `Registration`, then for each `Registration` object, it has `polyclinic` key which contains an object of `Polyclinic`.